# Debug simple java code related to Calendar Date GMT

Tags: java, date, calendar, gmt

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        Calendar dateFromNet = strToCal("11-MAR-2004", "dd-MMM-yyyy");
        Calendar IEndTime = strToCal("20-05-2004", "dd-mm-yyyy");

        if (dateFromNet.after(IEndTime) ) {

            System.out.println(dateFromNet);
            System.out.println(IEndTime);

            System.out.println("not true: 11-MAR-2004(11-3-2004) > 20-05-2004 ");
        }


    }

    private static Calendar strToCal(String date, String format) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat input = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        input.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

        Date d = (Date) input.parse(date);
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(d);
        return c;
    }
}
```

This test shows

```
dateFromNet.after(IEndTime) == true
```

i.e.  11-03-2004 is after 20-05-2004

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Calendar IEndTime = strToCal("20-05-2004", "dd-mm-yyyy");
```

mm is for milliseconds; make those capitol M, like this:

```
Calendar IEndTime = strToCal("20-05-2004", "dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Answer (score 1):

The letter, `m` and `M` have different meanings as shown in the following table:

| Letter | Date or Time Component | Presentation | Examples |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| m | Minute in hour | Number | 30 |
| M | Month in year | Month | July; Jul; 07 |

So, the root cause of the problem is using `m` instead of `M` in the pattern, `dd-mm-yyyy`.

## *java.time*

The legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting type, `SimpleDateFormat`) is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Demo of the modern API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ZonedDateTime dateFromNet = strToZdt("11-MAR-2004", "d-MMM-u");
        ZonedDateTime IEndTime = strToZdt("20-05-2004", "d-M-u");

        if (dateFromNet.isAfter(IEndTime)) {
            System.out.println("11-MAR-2004 > 20-05-2004");
        } else if (dateFromNet.isBefore(IEndTime)) {
            System.out.println("11-MAR-2004 < 20-05-2004");
        } else {
            System.out.println("11-MAR-2004 = 20-05-2004");
        }
    }

    private static ZonedDateTime strToZdt(String date, String format) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                .parseCaseInsensitive()
                                .appendPattern(format)
                                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date, dtf);

        return localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
11-MAR-2004 < 20-05-2004
```

If at all you need an object of `java.util.Calendar` from this object of `ZonedDateTime`, you can do so as follows:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(Date.from(dateFromNet.toInstant()));
```

Learn more about the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>